# useSWR not picking updated state variable

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

The `token` variable is not updating in SWR as I update it via `useState` in revalidate function.

```js
const [token, setToken] = useState('')

console.log(token) // this updates as setToken is called

const fetcher = (url) => {
    console.log(token) // this remains empty although it re-renders

    return axios.get(
        url,
        {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        },
    )
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(error => {//whatever})
}

const { data: user, error, revalidate } = useSWR('_ENDPOINT_', fetcher)

const login = (email, password) => {
    axios.post('/login', {email, password})
        .then((response) => { 
            setToken(response.data.token)
            revalidate()
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up using:

```
'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('_token').
            replace(/['"]+/g, '')}`,

 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` // instead of this using from useState which didn't update in ages
```

Because it appears localStorage was available after useSWR init; (even on page refreshes)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `useCallback` on the `fetcher` function for it to properly pick up the `token` state variable change.

```js
const fetcher = useCallback(
    (url) => {
        console.log(token) // Will log the updated `token` value
        return axios
            .get(
                url,
                { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } }
            )
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(error => {/*whatever*/})
    },
    [token]
)
```

---

A better solution, to avoid using `useCallback`, would be to move the `fetcher` function outside the component, and pass several arguments to the `fetcher` in the `useSWR` call. This has the benefit of using the `token` as the key for the request (in addition to the URL, making the caching more specific), and only making the request when `token` is defined.

```js
const fetcher = (url, token) => {
    return axios
        .get(
            url,
            { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } }
        )
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(error => {/*whatever*/})
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState('')

    const { data: user, error, revalidate } = useSWR(token ? ['_ENDPOINT_', token] : null, fetcher)

    // Rest of the component
}
```